# BigQuery and IPV6 Network issue

Tags: google-bigquery, ipv6

I usualy use BigQuery command line tool to load large datafiles without any problems.

I used US bigQuery data center, but, for security & legacy purposes, i switched to EU data center.

While doing that, bq use now my IPV6 network instead of IPV4 one to send data and falls down from 400Mbit/s to 30Mbit/s.

Do you have any idea why this append ? Is the IPV6 network interface in cause ? Or is there any other explanation ?

Thanks a lot for you help !